# Creating a simple P2P network

Tags: c#, asp.net, web, p2p, blockchain

I am attempting to create my own version of a cryptocurrency by using a BlockChain in a P2P network. I would like users to access my website then download an executable that allows them join the network and mine for currency. I also would like my website(c#) to display the updated ledger of the blockchain. I have done a lot of research, with little success, attempting to understand how to construct the P2P network.

**What would be the recommended language to construct this executable?** Are there any tutorials or examples that are suggested? In addition, **how would my website access the universal ledger?** Is it feasible to have my website's server also join the P2P network, or should the P2P network continuously send the ledger to my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blockchain is a very complex technology to understand not to mention inventing something like that with C# language.

I might want to start with ***Ethereum*** which uses ***solidity*** language similar to JavaScript.

If you would like to use C#, you might want to look at [Nethereum](https://github.com/Nethereum/Nethereum) *(.Net integration library for Ethereum)*.

Comment: I understand that the BlockChain is pretty complicated. I have currently created a program that allows users to add to a centralized ledger. I really just want to create a program that a user can download, join a p2p network, then send their current version of the ledger to each other. To me, this seems as simple as sending a text message to all peers in the network.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is language agnostic. Any language that can be built on different platforms. Actually,  I saw a book about blockchain implementation in python. But also there are courses on Java.

Comment: I understand that. I am more interested in knowing which language would be easiest/simplest.

Comment: C# and Python for me

Answer (score 0):

As Dmitry mentioned this is language agnostic.

Regarding C#: we have [Bitcoin and Stratis full node implementations](https://github.com/stratisproject/StratisBitcoinFullNode) in .NET, which may be your best reference. As Win said, it's a complex technology, so expect years of development until you can roll out a buggy alpha version, assuming you are doing it alone.

You may also want to get some experience first, for that, take a look at the book: [Programming the Blockchain in C#](https://github.com/ProgrammingBlockchain).

Then go and try building your product based on the above mentioned reference implementations.

> What would be the recommended language to construct this executable?

Historically lazy altcoin devs just cloned Litecoin and changed some parameters so C++ is what most alts are written in, but again: it's language agnostic.

> In addition, how would my website access the universal ledger?

That's your smallest problem. If you succeed to roll out an alt, then by the time you will know it.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of language depends on networking requirements and validation requirements.

For a completely decentralized use case, faster cryptographic verification is a need & thus languages native to the machine offer a speed advantage (like c++, golang).

If there is any element of centralization like private blockchain, permissioned blockchain, premined, asset-backed token, virtual machine blockchains like evm, colored coin etc. then access control and development requirements overtake permissionless and security requirements & thus language with available human resource should be chosen like c#, java etc.